# Local "retransmits" of HTTPS requests - Seeing this in Axis2-based WebApp

Tags: ssl, tcp, websphere, apache-axis

I have been observing a strange behaviour in my axis2-based (1.4.1) webapplication (running in Websphere 7). 
If my soap-based Webservice-request is blocked in the server-thread for exactly 60 seconds, I receive the Webservice-request again; more specific: my server-side SOAP message receiver is invoked again for that call (the first thread is still blocking at this time and the client application has received a timeout already 30 seconds ago).

I have been trying to trace this down; but did not succeed to understand the behaviour. Here are the facts that I have already:

**Fact 1**: It only happens with SSL enabled

**Fact 2**: The axis1-based webservice-client is not the one doing the retransmits; neither is it the client at all. I have been sniffing the outgoing packets at the client and incoming packets at the server and even though I cannot see the contents, based on the time, the retransmit is not going over the network.

**Fact 3** (based on Facts 1+2): The "resend" must be initiated somewhere between the NIC and JRE (IBM JRocket 9 VM) on the SERVER-side.

Initially this problem happend in my application beacause the call was blocking on a database-request but I have been simulation it with setting a break-point in the server for this request.

Sorry that I cannot provide any useful traces/logs to back up my "facts", but I was hoping that I might be missing something fairly obvious here... Obviously, the application layer should not see any retransmits; tcp should know what packages have been delivered to the upper layer; so, i would assume the problem could be somewhere close to the HTTP(S) protocol layer implementation in java???

Also, any good idea how to track this down would be highly appreciated. SSL beeing involved in the problem makes it all a litte harder...

***Edit***: I just did some more test and can now add some more facts to the equation:

***Fact 4***: To be really sure it is not comiming from the client, I unplugged the network-cable after sending the first webservice-request. The retransmit happend; so, it is definitvley happening at server-side.

***Fact 5***: I added a servlet-filter to see if it is triggered for the retransmit. It is; so, the retransmit must be, like expected, triggered between NIC and servelt engine on the server; somewhere in the JVM runtime or at TCP level.

***Fact 6***: The retransmit only happens if other data is going to the same TCPport in between. I.e. if i do not send some additional packages/requests after the initial webservice-request, the retransmit does not happen. Does this help to explain it with some problems in teh TCP layer?

I am running a rather older RedHat Enterprise Linux: Linux 2.6.9-89.EL

Thanks in advance,
Daniel